# Question related to matrix in computer memory

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

I'm trying to solve the following problem from a book:

> A matrix $\mathbb M$ has 3 rows and 4 columns:
>
> $$\left[ \begin{array}{cccc} 
> a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14}\\
> a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24}\\ 
> a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34}\\ 
> \end{array} \right]$$
>
> The 12 entries in the matrix are to be stored in row major form in
>   locations 7,609 to 7,620 in a computer’s memory. This means that the
>   entries in the ﬁrst row (reading left to right) are stored ﬁrst, then
>   the entries in the second row, and ﬁnally the entries in the third
>   row.
>   Find formulas (in $n$) for $r$ and $s$ so that $a_{rs}$ is stored in
>   location 7,609 + $n$.

So far I have come up with this relation among $r$, $s$ and $n$ (which is fairly common in matrix calculations):

$$4 \cdot (r-1) + s - 1 = n$$

But I can't seem to find the second relation that will allow me to express $r$ and $s$ in terms of $n$. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the rows, we want to come up with a function that will map $\{0,1,2,3\}$ to $1$, $\{4,5,6,7\}$ to $2$, and $\{8,9,10,11\}$ to $3$. This suggests that we use a floor function as follows:
$$
r=1+\lfloor n/4 \rfloor
$$

---

For the columns, we want to come up with a function that will map $\{0,4,8\}$ to $1$, $\{1,5,9\}$ to $2$, $\{2,6,10\}$ to $3$, and $\{3,7,11\}$ to $4$. This suggests that we take the remainder as follows:
$$
s=1+(n \bmod 4)
$$

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much! I did try all this while to find out a relation. I was trying variations of $\lfloor n/4 \rfloor + 1 - (-1)^n$, which was of course not working. 
In retrospect, it should have been easy to anticipate the functions, given that this chapter had introduced div and mod. :)

Comment: Also formally (using $0\le s-1<4$) we have $\lfloor\frac{4(r-1)+(s-1)}{4}\rfloor =r-1$ and $4(r-1)+(s-1)\equiv s-1\pmod 4$